# Quantmod chartSeries not working with some stocks

Tags: r, quantmod, quantitative-finance

I'm very new to R and quantmod. I tried this with AAPL and it works really fine:

```
getSymbols(Symbols = "AAPL", 
           env = parent.frame(),
           reload.Symbols = FALSE,
           verbose = FALSE,
           warnings = TRUE,
           src = "yahoo",
           symbol.lookup = TRUE,
           auto.assign = getOption("getSymbols.auto.assign",TRUE))

chartSeries(AAPL)
```

But the same thing with bitcoin doesn't seem to work:

```
getSymbols(Symbols = "BTC-EUR", 
           env = parent.frame(),
           reload.Symbols = FALSE,
           verbose = FALSE,
           warnings = TRUE,
           src = "yahoo",
           symbol.lookup = TRUE,
           auto.assign = getOption("getSymbols.auto.assign",TRUE))

chartSeries(BTC-EUR)
```

I get this error:

> Error in inherits(x, "xts") : object 'BTC' not found

I also tried `chartSeries("BTC-EUR")` and I get this:

> Error in try.xts(x, error = "chartSeries requires an xtsible object")
>   :    chartSeries requires an xtsible object

It does not work with the french CAC too from Yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

This is not due to the `quantmod` package. It is a matter of the data provider and the symbols that it uses.

Since the Bitcoin cryptocurrency is not a stock, it does not have a unique ticker which is commonly used to identify a security in the stock market. The same holds for the French CAC, which is a stock market *index*, and not a stock.

Financial data provider have special symbols for currencies, commodities, financial indexes etc. In the case of Bitcoin, yahoo finance lists the data with the symbol `BTCUSD=X`, which is the value of Bitcoin in USD.

This can be used to download the Bitcoin / USD time series from yahoo finance:

```
getSymbols(Symbols = "BTCUSD=X",  src="yahoo",
           [...add other options here])
```

For the CAC40 stock index, yahoo finance uses the symbol `^FCHI`.